# How to upsample a multi-index dataframe ensuring each grouping covers the same time range (provide custom starting and ending datetimes)

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Here is a dummy example to illustrate the problem.

I am interested in upsampling to the beginning of the each year (`AS`) and, for every country, I want to cover the period that goes from 1995 to the year 2000.

Imagine we had the following dataset:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [
        '1995-01-01', '1997-01-01', 
        '1997-01-01', '1998-01-01', '2000-01-01',
        '1996-01-01', '1999-01-01', 
    ],
    'country': [
        'ES', 'ES', 
        'GB', 'GB', 'GB',
        'DE', 'DE',
    ],
    'members': [
        100, 101, 
        200, 201, 202,
        300, 301,
    ]
})
df['year']= pd.to_datetime(df['year'])
df = df.set_index(['country', 'year'])
print(df)
```

```
                    members
country year               
ES      1995-01-01      100
        1997-01-01      101

GB      1997-01-01      200
        1998-01-01      201
        2000-01-01      202

DE      1996-01-01      300
        1999-01-01      301
```

As you can see, no country has data available for all the years between 1995 to 2000. Notice that some countries are also missing the year 1995 and other are missing the year 2000.

I know how to upsample the dataframe so that, for each country, it fills the years missing in between (e.g. adds the year 1996 to Spain).

```py
def my_upsample(df):
    return (
        df
        .reset_index('country')               # upsampling multi-index wit the keyword level is not supported
        .groupby('country', group_keys=False) # hence this little trick of single-indexing & grouping
                                            # see this issue for details: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28313
        .resample('AS') # resample to the beggining of each year
        .apply({
            'country':'pad',    # pad the countries
            'members':'asfreq', # but leave the number of members as NaN. Irrelevant in this dummy example, but 
                                # the desired behaviour in my real-world problem
        })
    )

print(my_upsample(df))
```

```
           country  members
year                       
1996-01-01      DE    300.0
1997-01-01      DE      NaN
1998-01-01      DE      NaN
1999-01-01      DE    301.0

1995-01-01      ES    100.0
1996-01-01      ES      NaN
1997-01-01      ES    101.0

1997-01-01      GB    200.0
1998-01-01      GB    201.0
1999-01-01      GB      NaN
2000-01-01      GB    202.0
```

But what I would like to do is make sure that all the countries cover the period from 1995 to 2000.

The desired output should look like this:

```
           country  members
year                       
1995-01-01      DE      NaN
1996-01-01      DE    300.0
1997-01-01      DE      NaN
1998-01-01      DE      NaN
1999-01-01      DE    301.0
2000-01-01      DE      NaN

1995-01-01      ES    100.0
1996-01-01      ES      NaN
1997-01-01      ES    101.0
1998-01-01      ES      NaN
1999-01-01      ES      NaN
2000-01-01      ES      NaN

1995-01-01      GB      NaN
1996-01-01      GB      NaN
1997-01-01      GB    200.0
1998-01-01      GB    201.0
1999-01-01      GB      NaN
2000-01-01      GB    202.0
```

I could use python loops iterating over each country and adding the missing rows (see code below), but I would like to know what is the pandas way of achieving this?

```py
for country in df.index.levels[0]:
    if not (country, '1995-01-01') in df.query(f"country == @country").index:
        # if this country doesn't have the year 1995 create the row with NaN as value
        df.loc[(country, '1995-01-01'),:] = np.nan 

    if not (country, '2000-01-01') in df.query(f"country == @country").index:
        # if this country doesn't have the year 2000 create the row with NaN as value
        df.loc[(country, '2000-01-01'),:] = np.nan
print(df.sort_index())
```

```
                    members
country year               
DE      1995-01-01      NaN
        1996-01-01    300.0
        1999-01-01    301.0
        2000-01-01      NaN
ES      1995-01-01    100.0
        1997-01-01    101.0
        2000-01-01      NaN
GB      1995-01-01      NaN
        1997-01-01    200.0
        1998-01-01    201.0
        2000-01-01    202.0
```

And then running `my_upsample` returns the desired output:

```py
print(my_upsample(df.sort_index()))
```

```
           country  members
year                       
1995-01-01      DE      NaN
1996-01-01      DE    300.0
1997-01-01      DE      NaN
1998-01-01      DE      NaN
1999-01-01      DE    301.0
2000-01-01      DE      NaN

1995-01-01      ES    100.0
1996-01-01      ES      NaN
1997-01-01      ES    101.0
1998-01-01      ES      NaN
1999-01-01      ES      NaN
2000-01-01      ES      NaN

1995-01-01      GB      NaN
1996-01-01      GB      NaN
1997-01-01      GB    200.0
1998-01-01      GB    201.0
1999-01-01      GB      NaN
2000-01-01      GB    202.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way, but here is one way to achieve this:

```
def my_upsample(df):
    # Get all periods
    years = df.index.get_level_values(1)
    years = pd.date_range(years.min(), years.max(), freq="as")

    # Reindex and format
    return (
        df.unstack(level=0)
        .reindex(years)
        .unstack()
        .reset_index((0, 1), name="members")
        .drop("level_0", axis=1)
    )
```

Output:

```
           country  members
1995-01-01      DE      NaN
1996-01-01      DE    300.0
1997-01-01      DE      NaN
1998-01-01      DE      NaN
1999-01-01      DE    301.0
2000-01-01      DE      NaN
1995-01-01      ES    100.0
1996-01-01      ES      NaN
1997-01-01      ES    101.0
1998-01-01      ES      NaN
1999-01-01      ES      NaN
2000-01-01      ES      NaN
1995-01-01      GB      NaN
1996-01-01      GB      NaN
1997-01-01      GB    200.0
1998-01-01      GB    201.0
1999-01-01      GB      NaN
2000-01-01      GB    202.0
```

Here's some explanation of each step:

1. `unstack(level=0)`: Pivot the index (the `level=0` part sets "year" as the index, thus allowing the incoming reindexing)
2. `reindex(years)`: Reindex to the target date range. Notice in your specific example this wouldn't actually be required, since your sample already contains all years at least once;
3. `unstack()`: Pivot yet again. As the index is not a `MultiIndex`, pivotting here will return a `Series` with a hierarchical index: "member" > "country" > "year". At this stage we're essentially done, just need to format this into the desired `DataFrame`;
4. `reset_index((0, 1), name='members')`: leave only the "year" as index and rename the original `Series` to "members";
5. `drop('level_0', axis=1)`: drop the unwanted column

Comment: This is excellent! Do you think you could explain a bit what's going on and why this works? I can see it does but I don't think I follow what happens with the indices (too many levels for my little brain?) from `unstack` to `reindex` and then `unstack` again. Thanks for your help!

PS: since you think there must be a better way I'm waiting a little longer before accepting your answer, just to see if we catch someone else attention :)

Comment: Sure thing! I added a slightly improved version (dropped an unnecessary `swaplevel`) and explained a bit of the logic. I hope is clear enough.